# How to inject dataProvider in repository using bloc pattern

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

As follow the bloc official repository pattern, it suggest the repository with multi-dataProvider, but how should I inject the dataProvider in the repository?

```
class Repository {
    final DataProviderA dataProviderA;  // What's the way to init the DataProviderA in the repository.
    final DataProviderB dataProviderB;

    Future<Data> getAllDataThatMeetsRequirements() async {
        final RawDataA dataSetA = await dataProviderA.readData();
        final RawDataB dataSetB = await dataProviderB.readData();

        final Data filteredData = _filterData(dataSetA, dataSetB);
        return filteredData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow official Weather example https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterweathertutorial?id=repository 
You can in `main()` init `Repository` and inject `dataProviderA` and `dataProviderB` 
code snippet

```
class Repository {
  final DataProviderA dataProviderA;
  final DataProviderB dataProviderB;

  Repository({@required this.dataProviderA, @required this.dataProviderB})
      : assert(dataProviderA != null && dataProviderB != null);

  Future<Data> getAllDataThatMeetsRequirements() async {
    final RawDataA dataSetA = await dataProviderA.readData();
    final RawDataB dataSetB = await dataProviderB.readData();

    final Data filteredData = _filterData(dataSetA, dataSetB);
    return filteredData;
  }
}

void main() {
  Bloc.observer = SimpleBlocObserver();

  final Repository repository = Repository(
    dataProviderA: DataProviderA(),
    dataProviderB: DataProviderB(),
  );

  runApp(App(repository: repository));
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final Repository repository;

  App({Key key, @required this.repository})
      : assert(repository != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Weather',
      home: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => YourBloc(repository: repository),
        child: YourMainEntry(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```